# Producing timestamp in correct format using Pentaho DI

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I am using Data Integration to get data from our online API. Apart of the data is a timestamp and this is printed like so on the website `1389227435641` but when it is printed up on a table it is printed like so `1.389227435641E12`

How do I get it to print like it is from the website and not like the way it is now?

Comment: can you explain which and all steps you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the API returning the number in scientific notation?

If you want to convert 1.389227435641E12 to another format, import it as a BigNumber then use Select Values and change the Format.

Comment: No the API is not showing the number in scientific notation. I tried but it wont accept it, saying it cant convert it